# Contact Form 7 - Related to shortcode and Value

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am creating a form using the contact form 7 plugin where the user is required to select 2 colors by selecting the checkboxes. **I have altered the style of the checkbox.** When the user submits the form, I need to receive the colors selected by the user.

When I use the standard checkbox, I receive the colors perfectly via email.

With the altered checkbox style, I don't receive the colors.

Where within the HTML, should I insert the shortcode provided by contact form 7 to receive the colors selected via email?

**The Contact Form 7 shortcode I am trying to use is**

```
[checkbox checkbox-red value "Red,"]
```

**The HTML Code is**

```
<div class="color-desktop">

<label class="color-container" for="red">
  <input class="single-check" type="checkbox" id="red">
  <span class="checkmark red"></span>
</label>

<label class="color-container" for="blue">
  <input class="single-check" type="checkbox" id="blue">
<span class="checkmark blue"></span>
</label>

<label class="color-container" for="green">
  <input class="single-check" type="checkbox" id="green">
  <span class="checkmark green"></span>
</label>
```

**The CSS used is**

```
/* Customize the label (the container) */
.color-container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 48px;
  margin-bottom: 48px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
.color-container input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

/* Create a custom checkbox */
.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}

/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

/* Show the checkmark when checked */
.color-container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
  display: block; 
}

/* Style the checkmark/indicator */
.color-container .checkmark:after {
  left: 10px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 13px;
  height: 22px;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 8px 8px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(40deg);
}

.checkmark.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.checkmark.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.checkmark.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

**The Javascript used is:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var limit = 2;
 var $checkboxes = $('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function(evt) {
 if ($checkboxes.filter(':checked').length > limit) {
 this.checked = false;
}
});
</script>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When you add another checkbox, one after the other there is a checkbox ID that is provided.

For example you CF7 will generate this shortcode:

```
[checkbox checkbox-661]
```

Go to the Mail tab and add this:

```
This is your checkbox: [checkbox-661]
```

Now whenever someone emails you, the selection of checkbox 661 will appear in your email like so:

```
This is your checkbox: value will appear here.
```